# Elaborated type specifier in type alias

Tags: c++, c++11, types, language-lawyer

Why is there no hard error in the following code? Type alias and name of class are exactly the same (compiler `clang`):

```
using S = struct S;

struct S {};

S s;

int main()
{
}
```

Which name exactly used in the definition of variable in the following code (symbol or type alias)?

```
using S = struct S {};

int main()
{
    S s;
}
```

Comment: Because C and its `typedef struct S {} S;`

Comment: `using S = struct S;` does not hide, but *re-defines* `S` to be both a typedef name and a class name (a single name that has two properties). You will often hear people say that `using S = struct S;` introduces two names and C++ will search multiple "symbol spaces", but that's not how it works in C++. An insightful discussion of this can be found at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#407 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below makes `S` an alias of a *struct* named `S`. The `using S` redefines the name `S` as an alias of `struct S`.

```
using S = struct S;
```

The line below defines that `struct S`.

```
struct S {};
```

The Declaration below, uses the `S` which as an alias of `S` as made by *using*.

```
S s;
```

Least to say, this is akin to

```
using K = struct S;

struct S { S(){ std::cout << "Constructed!\n"; } };

K s;

int main()
{    }
```

The code will print:

```
Constructed!
```

Basically, the name `K` will be replaced by `struct S`.

---

For your second example, its inherently the same as C's `typedef`:

```
typedef struct C {} C;
```

which is simply redundant in C++

Answer (score 2):

1. The first is a holdover from C, where tag-namespace (struct / union / enum) is completely separate from typename-namespace (typedef and builtin types).
   In C++ that rule is relaxed so if there's nothing in the typename-namespace, the tag-namespace is automatically searched.
2. The second is answered by considering the answer for the first:
   The typename is found.

Comment: WRT 1. so type aliases function like a `#define`? Just a text replacement?

Comment: Not quite like that, then there would not be two somewhat separate namespaces. Anyway, #define is evil.

Comment: `using S = struct S;` introduces two names in two different lookup tables (from compiler's point of view)?